# Multi module Spring boot structure for Microservice

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, microservices, netflix

We are developing application in micro service architecture using Netflix Open Sources libraries. What should be the module structure of the Micro-services designed in Spring Boot with Spring Data. I have thought a lot and also searched on internet but found no concrete solutions.

I thought of -

```
A-Service
      -- A-Service-Client ( Contains REST API Layer - controllers and DTO )
      -- A-Service-Repository (Contains Spring data repo and Models )
      -- A-Service-Server (Contains Implementation part )
```

If any one has better multi-module structure, please suggest it.

Comment: Does your `A-Service-Client` contains controllers implementation? I would personally split a microservice in at most 2 sub-modules: 1 for the external API (if you want to share the DTO's), which can be used as dependency for other modules, and the non-public part, the implementation, containing everything else (controllers, services, repos...)

Comment: Yes ..!! I agree with you @Tome. I will be using Feign Client so I might have to expose the controller So I will be putting it into Client. Server will contain all the implementation except Database layer , for that I have created Repository Module.

Comment: Given a "commons"-module containing model classes shared among various microservices, should I be creating a "parent"-project for each microservice (in order to tell it to build the commons project first and the actual microservice thereafter) OR would I make one parent-project for all microservices (since they'll be all developed in Java so far) and have it build commons first and all the other microservices thereafter?